# Stacktrace in lldb with clang built binary on OS X

Tags: xcode, clang, lldb

Once upon a time I was able to do the following on OS X with Xcode commandline tools installed, just as I normally did on Linux:

```
vim foo.cpp
#... write some buggy code that segfaults
gcc -g foo.cpp
gdb a.out
(gdb) bt
```

And I would see a nice, symbolicated stack trace. Nowadays, gdb has been replaced with lldb and gcc with clang. If I simply build with `clang++` and do `lldb a.out` I have no symbols.

I have tried running dsymutil and obtained a file of type `Mach-O 64-bit dSYM companion file x86_64` and tried loading this in lldb with `target symbols add`, still no symbols in the stacktrace. But I must admit, I gave up halfway through http://lldb.llvm.org/symbolication.html thinking it simply cannot be true to go through all these hoops and loops to get a flippin' stack trace from a binary I am producing myself.

So my question boils down to: What is the simplest way to achieve what I did above a few years ago with gcc and gdb on the commandline of a modern OS X system using the standard Xcode tools?

Please note is not an option to just install gcc and gdb using port or homebrew etc. - I need to build and obtain a stacktrace from the commandline using the standard Xcode tools.

Comment: Are you sure you did: "clang -g -O0 foo.cpp" when you built your binary?  If you did that, the steps with lldb should be exactly the same as with gdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Jim's comment made me make a full simple `foo.cpp` example from scratch and it indeed worked just as he described with nice symbolicated stack trace.

It turns out I just did not carefully read the output from `lldb` in the first place - the non-symbolicated stacktrace was actually not from my crash but from the `dyld` library loader that could not resolve an external dependency.

So the answer is that `lldb` and `clang` works exactly as I hoped for. I was just tricked by output like the following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libbarlib.dylib
 Referenced from: fooexe
  Reason: image not found
Process 776 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xec52b9, 0x00007fff5fc01075 dyld`dyld_fatal_error + 1, stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5fc01075 dyld`dyld_fatal_error + 1
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x7fff5fc01075 <+1>: nop    

dyld`dyldbootstrap::start:
    0x7fff5fc01076 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x7fff5fc01077 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7fff5fc0107a <+4>: pushq  %r15
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0xec52b9, 0x00007fff5fc01075 dyld`dyld_fatal_error + 1, stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff5fc01075 dyld`dyld_fatal_error + 1
    frame #1: 0x00007fff5fc03f87 dyld`dyld::halt(char const*) + 77
    frame #2: 0x00007fff5fc05fda dyld`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 4174
    frame #3: 0x00007fff5fc01276 dyld`dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 512
    frame #4: 0x00007fff5fc01036 dyld`_dyld_start + 54
```